# Calculating Nth percentile from table in ModelBuilder of ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, statistics, summarizing

I am trying to build a complex tool, using ModelBuilder and I am new at this.

I have two feature classes full of polygons:

The first contains 1300 polygons, dividing a city in zones (ex: residential, industrial, etc.). The second FC contains 35000 land parcels. Each parcel has unique data stored in the data table (area, width, depth, etc.).

As you can see in the screenshot, each Zone "contains" many Parcels.

[image: Zones & land parcels]

I need to summarize statistics for each zone. I have built this model using ModelBuilder. It makes a spatial join between my Land parcels and the Zones, so every Land Parcel will get a Zone ID (in the following screenshot). It will take the resulting feature class and iterate it by unique Zone ID. To calculate statistics, and export the result by creating a table for each Zone.

[image: Modelbuilder]

After that, I Merge the resulting tables to get a single table, with the stats for all Zones, as you can see here.

[image: Tables]

I can do all those things using the tools available in the ModelBuilder.
For example, the zone RES_810 contains 266 land parcels. The minimum area is 459.7m², the max is 1574.6m², but the mean is 645m². My problem is that I need to get the percentile 0.05 and 0.95 to eliminate extreme values: the 5% bottom, and 5% top.

The percentile is not an available option in the Summary Statistics tool.

How can I calculate the percentile 0.05 and 0.95, for each Zone, to include that statistic in my result tables?

Comment: Sort table in ascending order,  select records inside interval, calc statistics.